# ABS Traction control / fiddle brakes

Tags: electrical-engineering, hydraulics

I have an 4x4 which I have heavily modified, the only thing missing is mechanical differential locks. I think it wouldn't be too hard to fit a four channel abs pump from another vehicle and produce my own controller. Which would give me more or less the same ability as diff locks plus a few more features without the hefty price tag.
Features I intend to have are.

1. Individually locking a wheel on demand (just like fiddle brakes at the touch of a button for all 4 wheels)
2. Two potentiometers for automatic control of the amount of slip to allow between left and right wheels.
3. Automatic air stop. For detecting front wheel air (on jumps etc)to slow them to a min speed when we detect a run away difference between front and rear.(this will stop breakage of front drive components when they hit the ground).

I plan to monitor wheel speed with 4 hall effect sensors and abs rings fitted to each wheel. The control unit will be an arduino and will count pulses on interrupt.

The electronics and programming side of things I am quite proficient at.
The hydraulic side of things no so much.

I understand that these abs pumps have 4 channels and two feeds usually labelled mc1 mc2, I assume one for front and one for rear from the master cylinder.
each channel is controlled by a three way valve. This is where my knowledge runs out.

My question then is how are these valves usually controlled in terms of positions and electrical connection?

Whats the maximum / typical frequency these valves actuate at or is it variable depending on rotational speed?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a highly specialized automotive question. Recommend migration to http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Not really mechanics. More related to these solenoid valves, they are used thought industry and not specifically to automotive. Not sure the best place for the question hence general engineering. But fair point the second question is probably specific to automotive applications.

Comment: If this is a "full size" vehicle (not something like an RC model), since the OP is in the UK there could be some serious legal issues involved if the modified vehicle was ever going to be used on public roads - for example, how to keep the modified vehicle compliant with the MOT (safety test) regulations for traction control and ABS brakes, and whether an insurance company would provide  cover for it.

Comment: This is for off-road use only. Yes this is a full sized vehicle